# Why is ntfs-3g not included anymore by default?

Tags: ntfs

Why is ntfs-3g not included anymore in Ubuntu 11.10?

Now I can't write to my NTFS partition.

Just curiosity, why the change?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found out that ntfsprogs has write support for NTFS. And thus it replaces ntfs-3g.

But this package is still a bit buggy and sometimes it doesn't work so you can't create new folders and files on the NTFS filesystems.

So it is working on a random base xD.

In Ubuntu things should be tested more properly. Because they just replaced a working package with a buggy one.

Comment: The package says ntfs-3g replaced ntfsprogs, not the other way.

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK `ntfs-3g` is included in the default Ubuntu installation, because the virtual `ubuntu-standard` package depends on it. You've probably uninstalled it by mistake.

Check the output of

```
dpkg -l ntfs*
```

If you see something like **rc** for the package, you've uninstalled it.

EDIT:

From your comments it looks like you installed `ntfsprogs`. If that is true, then by installing it you automatically uninstalled `ntfs-3g`, as these two packages are in conflict (in Oneiric). `ntfs-3g` now provides the functionality of `ntfsprogs` so it's not needed.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The ntfs-3g package is not installed, when I try to install it, apt says it will remove ntfsprogs. So continue?

Comment: By the way, mine is a fresh ubuntu installation, so it is not included by default.

Answer (score 3):

[NTFS-3G](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS-3G) ***is*** still included in Ubuntu 11.10. (See information about `ntfs-3g` in Oneiric [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/ntfs-3g) and [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ntfs-3g).) I am using it on two Ubuntu 11.10 machines at this very moment!

While the NTFS filesystem was developed by Microsoft for use in their proprietary Windows operating system, there is nothing proprietary in `ntfs-3g`, and `ntfs-3g` is completely independent of any "restricted extras" package.

`ntfs-3g` is also still installed by default in Ubuntu 11.10. In the very unlikely event that it has become uninstalled, you can reinstall it by installing the `ntfs-3g` package.

If you uninstalled `ntfs-3g`, you would no longer be able to mount NTFS volumes and write to them. (You would then be using the older NTFS driver which only had experimental--and generally not safe--support for writing to NTFS filesystems.) But in practice, problems mounting and writing to NTFS volumes in Ubuntu are not caused by `ntfs-3g` being missing--they are caused by other, more subtle, things going wrong. Fortunately, they are rare, virtually always correctable, and usually fixable with relative ease.

I recommend that you post a new question detailing information about the drive you are having trouble mounting (including its size, make, and model). If this is not an external drive but is instead a partition on the same drive as your Ubuntu system, then specify its size (if you know it or can find out), whether or not it has Windows installed on it and if so what version of Windows, and specifically how you installed Ubuntu. Make sure to indicate if writing to the partition is the only problem you're having, or if you are also unable to mount it and/or read it. If you are able to mount the drive, you should include the output of the `mount` command (run just like that, with no arguments) in the Terminal.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me, looks like I was having some misunderstanding, deleting my comment :)

Comment: It is possible to mount NTFS volumes without the `ntfs-3g` package. Just try it! :)

Comment: @arrange You're right, of course; it just wouldn't be nearly as good support as we have with `ntfs-3g`. I've edited my answer to provide an explanation that is correct, and more detailed, on that point. Falling back on the old linux ntfs driver would also be consistent with [giowck](http://askubuntu.com/users/11928/giowck)'s [problem](http://askubuntu.com/q/83838/22949). I'll be interested to hear if this  problem really was due to `ntfs-3g` being uninstalled.

Comment: @EliahKagan: me too...